# Benefits and Disadvantages for subclassing NotificationCenter

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

I am quite new to Swift. In all the examples of `NotificationCenter` I have seen, the default `NotificationCenter.default` is used. However I have tested it is possible to subclass `NotificationCenter` and use custom objects to post and listen notification.

```
import Foundation

struct Notice {
    let num: Int
    let str: String
}

class TestObj: NotificationCenter {
    private var number = 0
    override init() {
        number = 5
    }
    
    func postNotification(_ num: Int) {
        post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "TestObjNotification"), object: Notice(num: num, str: "No is \(num)"))
    }
}

class Watcher: NSObject {
    var obj = TestObj()
    
    func addWatchers() {
        obj.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(watched(noti:)), name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "TestObjNotification"), object: nil)
    }
    
    func watch(num: Int) {
        obj.postNotification(num)
    }
    
    @objc func watched(noti: NSNotification) {
        print(noti.name.rawValue)
        print(noti.object!)
        guard let noticeObj = noti.object as? Notice else {
            print("Not working")
            return
        }
        print(noticeObj.num)
        print(noticeObj.str)
    }
}

let watcherObj = Watcher()
watcherObj.addWatchers()
watcherObj.watch(num: 500)
```

I would prefer this approach as this would ensure grouping notifications to specific types rather than maintaining notifications for app wide. Also it is possible to implement ObservableObject functionality with these custom types for iOS 12 and before. My concern is that:

- Is there any performance penalty for this?
- What happens when custom `NotificationCenter` is deallocated? Does all the listeners need to stop listening? What happens when all the listeners register for the same notifications. Since `NotificationCenter.default` is read-only there isn't any issue regarding this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you should prefer composition over inheritence. I would not recommend subclassing here. A TestObj **isn't** a notification center. You could configure it so that TestObj **has a** notification center, if you like:

```
class TestObj {
    var notificationCenter: NotificationCenter
    private var number = 5
    override init(notificationCenter: NotificationCenter) {
        self.notificationCenter = notificationCenter
    }
    
    func postNotification(_ num: Int) {
        notificationCenter.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "TestObjNotification"), object: Notice(num: num, str: "No is \(num)"))
    }
}
```

Now you are free to worry about the lifetime of any passed-in notification center beyond the lifetime of TestObj.